# Which is better listview usability in Android?

Tags: android

I want to add a listview in android app. In listview must to be text and picture area. Where must I put picture left from the text or right from the text for better usability?

- PICTURE - TEXT
- **OR**
- TEXT - PICTURE

For example:

1. Contact name - contact photo
2. Company name - company logo
3. Shot photo location - photo preview
   ....
   etc.

Comment: whats problem and what title you enter? is it related to your question ?

Comment: May have been better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com/ but the standard has always and will probably always be Photo then Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize your listview to your requirement, whichever way you want to do it, is completely up to you and there is no preference as such. But generally what I have observed is that the Photo is on the left and the Text after that and looks aesthetically better.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no such rule but it is always better to put image in the left and text to the right of image because **A picture says more than a thousand words:** 
To achieve this you need to create Custom List View. see [tutorial on Custom ListView](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/advanced-listview-populating-a-list-with-images-and-text/)

If you do the same (image in left and text in the right) then you may get result like the following image

[image]